# Date validation using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have start date and end date picker in format of mm-dd-yyyy.End date should be with in 10 days range of start date and end date should not be before start date. How to validate using angular js.Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use moment.js. Here's a basic tutorial and help to get started:
https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-momentjs-intro-with-examples

Basically you would do:

```
function testDate(startDate, endDate){
    var start =  moment(startDate, 'mm-dd-yyyy');
    var end = moment(endDate, 'mm-dd-yyyy');
    if(endDate.isBefore(start)){
       //start before end
    }
    if(startDate.add('days', 11).isAfter(endDate)){
       //end not within 10 days range
    }
    //success!
}
```

It would be something like that. Hope it helps!

Comment: I need with out using moment.js

Comment: I do not want to use moment.js.That is not permitted due to some reasons

Answer (score 0):

For simple pattern matching, you can use the `ngPattern` directive. For more complex validation (such as ensuring it's a valid date and within a certain range of another date), you will need to write your own validation directive or use the handy custom validation directive available from Angular-UI.

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about this as in what library are you using for datepicker. It would help us answer.

Since you are using a datepicker you can restrict the date range in the fromDate field do not display any dates which are after a certain period (10 days from start date in you case).

[jQuery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) allows this so does other datepickers.

**EDIT:**
In your controller do something like this.

```
var newDate = new Date($scope.startdate.getFullYear(), $scope.startdate.getMonth(), $scope.startdate.getDate()+10);
$scope.dateOptions = {
 maxDate: newDate,
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/YYYY'
};
```

And now you can pass dateOptions to your input.

**Note:** Post a minimal plunkr for faster resolution of your issues.

Comment: I am using <input type=“text” ui-date ui-date-format ng-model=“startdate” ></input> .I am using same for end date date  picker  with different model name.Could you please help validating max date should be 10 days from start date

Comment: How to pass date options to input?I am new to angular js?Could you provide sample code?

Comment: try `<input type=“text” ui-date="dateOptions"  ng-model=“startdate”/>`

Comment: I got an error TypeError:Cannot read property ‘getFullYear’ of undefined.

Comment: Can you post your code in a plunkr so that its easier for me to see what's going on?
you can find a reference plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7x2iz8tnnEC2mnsvLAK)

Comment: I cannot as the access is prohibited in my office

Comment: Could you post  code if possible for working example of date picker with start and end date ?End date be date picker consisting of 10 days from start date

Comment: Here is a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIVevAmVTZfNoDR9dmSv)

Accept the answer if that helps

Comment: But the start date should be dynamically selected from date picker.It should not be current date.Based on the dynamically selected start date end date should be 10 days from start date

Comment: you can always modify the plunkr. Do not initialise the startdate, and that'll solve your problem

Comment: When I do not instantiate with new Date() I get typeError